# How to find all documents that don't have an array or it is smaller than

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find all documents, which either don't have an array `tags` or the size of the array is smaller than 2. How do I do this? I'm trying this, but doesn't work:

```
db.collection.find({
  'text' => { '$exists' => true }, # I need this one too
  'tags' => {
    '$or' => [
      { '$exists' => false },
      { '$lt' => ['$size', 2] }
    ]
  }
})
```

It's Ruby, btw. MongoDB version is 4.

I'm getting:

```
unknown operator: $or
```

Comment: In what way is this not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query

```
db.collection.find({
  text: { $exists: true },
  $or: [{
    tags: { $exists: false }
  }, {
    $expr: { $lt: [{ $size: '$tags' }, 2] }
  }]
})
```

Comment: This is the weirdest formatting I've seen for Mongo, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

To slightly modify MauriRamone's answer to a smaller version:

```js
db.getCollection('test').find({
         $and:[
               {"text":{$exists:true} }, 
               {$where: "!this.tags || this.tags.length < 2"}
              ]
         })
```

However, [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) is slow, and other options (such as Anthony's) should be preferred.

Your original query wasn't working because [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) only works in **expressions**, not in fields, and you need an `$expr` operator for the size.

Comment: I'm getting: `$where is not allowed in this context`

Answer (score 0):

try using $were in your query, like this:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
         $and:[
               {"text":{$exists:true} }, 
               {
                $or:[
                    {"tags":{$exists:false}},
                    {$where: "this.tags.length < 2"}
                    ]
               }
               ] 
         })
```

I am using Robomongo to test, you should format the query to Ruby.
regards.